# Issue with Thread.SetAffinity and Threading via XNA on the Xbox 360

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360

So I developed a very efficient collision detection system, but the problem is that it still cannot run on the main thread since it's too damn slow.

I tried setting up some threading, and if the thread ends, another thread is created.

```
if (doneCollisions)
            {
                PopulateGrid();
            }


            if (doneCollisions)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckCollisionsGrid));

                thread.Start();

            }

void CheckCollisionsGrid()
{
Thread.CurrentThread.SetProcessorAffinity(3);
            doneCollisions = false;
            //Increments through all the grids.
.
.
.
doneCollisions = true;
}
```

Now I noticed some odd behaviour when debugging.  When I called Thread.SetAffinity, it sort of jumped back to it over and over once or twice before finally starting to actually check the collisions.

And now my collisions are delayed by 5-10 seconds...

If anyone has insight please input some here.

Comment: imho, the affinity is such low, that the scheduler will "try to begin the action" but reverts that, because there are "better things to do" (wich a higher affinity)...
only after 5-10seconds the scheduler finds a slot for your action...

Comment: @TheHe I thought SetAffinity set's which core to use?  What do you suggest to improve my threading? If I just create a new thread it lags, because 2 threads on 1 core isn't that nice.

Comment: aah.. 4sure you're right... i was @ priorities and something..

first: does the xbox have 4 processors?!
second: check this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684251(v=vs.85).aspx
third: set the thread-priority lower?

Comment: The Xbox only has 3 cores, and one of them (0, if my memory doesn't fail) is reserved for the console's OS, so setting affinity to 3 (fourth processor) would be useless. I'm not sure that's the problem, but try setting it to 1 or 2, or reading documentation regarding such stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XBOX 360 has 3 cores with 2 hardware threads per core, producing a total of 6 hardware threads.
Threads 0 and 2 are reserved by the XNA Framework, leaving 1, 3, 4 and 5 for you to use.

As for the question, why are you creating a new thread after checking for collisions, to do exactly the same all over again? If you need to repeat the collision checking in a thread, simply put it inside a `while(true)` loop to keep it going.

Comment: Well, I did do exactly what you said, except without the while(true) loop, which is silly.

Comment: Not exactly silly. Creating & tearing-down threads is an expensive operation. Use an endless loop (I prefer for(;;)) and some synchronization primitives.